# how to make vim's auto-complete behave like bash's default auto-complete?

Tags: bash, vim, autocomplete

When you type :e `some/path/file<Tab>` if there are several matches, vim just picks the first one and you have to cycle through the rest of them with the Tab key. (pretty much like the behavior of the Windows CLI).

How do I make it behave like bash where it only completes until there's ambiguity?

*EDIT*: updated question for a bit more clarity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569348/vim-in-ex-command-mode-how-to-complete-the-path-only-up-to-the-first-non-unique

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:longest
```

Comment: I just signed up to superuser and answered questions so that I could get enough reputation to upvote your answer. Thankyou.

Answer (score -4):

Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> multiple times steps through the matches.

You can omit `set wildmenu` since `set wildmode=list:longest` implies it.

Comment: I know ... that's not the question